# Actuator not working for spring boot reactive weblux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

With the following dependencies, the /actuator endpoint is showing 404. Please help me

I was expecting the management facilities to be available on 127.0.0.1:8081 i.e.

http://127.0.0.1:8081/health

But nothing loads on the endpoint, what have I done wrong? Actuator endpoints work in the case of a normal Spring Boot application. But is not working when I add it in the spring-webflux application. Even the logs are not showing the detected actuator endpoint.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>           
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
   <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.1.RELEASE</version>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-transport-native-unix-common</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The default path is `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health` which is clearly written out in the documentation (where you should start if something is not working) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints

Comment: Logs will probably not show anything if you exclude all log dependecies. And you also dont need to pull in the context as this already pulled in by all other spring dependencies. If you start a new project i suggest you use the spring initlzer to generate a project with correct dependencies because there is a lot wrong with yours